# How to intercept configuration of all ThreadPoolTaskExecutors?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-async

I'd like to intercept the creation of all `ThreadPoolTaskExecutors` inside the application context, and add all of them a custom `TaskDecorator`.

Pseudocode:

```
public void interceptTaskExecutors(List<ThreadPoolTaskExecutor> executors) {
    var decorator = new MyTaskDecorator();
    executors.stream().forEach(executor -> executor.setTaskDecorator(decorator));
}
```

But how can I actually intercept the bean initialization process of all `TaskExecutors` to apply this?

Comment: To prevent XY problem, please update the question with your use case.

Comment: That is what a `BeanPostProcessor` can do. Check type of bean, do something.

Answer (score 0):

@M. Deinum probably means as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class ThreadPoolCustomizer implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Autowired
    private TaskDecorator decorator;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof ThreadPoolTaskExecutor)
            ((ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) bean).setTaskDecorator(decorator);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be careful injecting a dependency into a `BeanPostProcessor`. It may cause lots of beans in your application to be initialized very early on as the context looks for the `TaskDecorator` bean. Unless it needs to be a bean for some reason, it would be better if your `BeanPostProcessor` created the decorator itself.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, will do so then!